# Scatter doesn't work properly Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote a code to create a movie of moving points. I used scatter to make points colored( color of points depends to the density of points of the area). x and y are position of points and I have put below code in a for loop for passing time:

```
figure(h1); % set figure 1 as current figure
cla
dens = zeros(size(x));
% Tolerence is distance betweeen points (squared)
tol = 1;
for ii = 1:numel(x)
    % Loop through all points, count neighbours within tolerence
    dens(ii) = sum((x - x(ii)).^2 + (y - y(ii)).^2 < tol);
end
% Normalise density onto range 0-1
dens = (dens/max(dens));
hold on
scatter(x,y, [], dens,'filled','d')
drawnow
currFrame = getframe;
writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);
```

When I run the code, the movie is created but all points are green. Could anyone guess what is the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: The fourth argument is supposed to be a 3 column matrix of `double` where each row is a RGB tuple with each element being `[0,1]`.  Is this the same for your `dens` array?

Comment: I try this but it didn't changed anything: figure(h1); 
    cla
    dens = zeros(size(x));
    % Tolerence is distance betweeen points (squared)
    tol = 1;
    
   for ii = 1:numel(x)
        % Loop through all points, count neighbours within tolerence
        dens(ii) = sum((x - x(ii)).^2 + (y - y(ii)).^2 < tol);
   end
    dens = (dens/max(dens));
    hold on
    cm = jet(100);
    scatter(x,y,[],cm(fix(size(cm,1)*dens)),'filled','d')
   % scatter(x,y, [], dens,'filled','d')
    drawnow
    currFrame = getframe;
    writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);

Comment: It becomes correct by changing tol to 100 @EBH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dens` calculation is dependent on the relation between the values of `x` and `y`, and the value of `tol`. If `tol` is too large, then all the points a counted as "in the region" of all other points, if it's too small, then all points are "alone". In both cases, `dens` has the same values for all points and `scatter` color them all in green.